# integral on a domain $D=\{|x|+|y|\le 1\}$

Tags: real-analysis

I have the function $f(x,y)=e^{x+y}$ and I want calculate $\int f dx dy$ on D.Is the integral null because D is symmetric ?

It's different if  I calculate $\int xe^{x+y} dx dy$ on $D=\{\sqrt{|x|}+\sqrt{|y|}\le 1\}$?

Comment: The integral is not null

Answer (score 0):

The principle of integrals being $0$ over symmetric regions is only reliable when $f$ is an odd function, or has some symmetry so that you know its values in one part of the region cancel its values in other parts. In this case, the function $f$ is always positive, so you shouldn't expect any cancellation.

This particular domain is a square with vertices at $(-1,0),(0,1),(1,0)$ and $(0,-1)$. (Do you see why?) The only symmetry that I could see exploiting is that $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$, where the region has the matching symmetry: $(x,y)\in D\implies (y,x)\in D$. Therefore you could split the region in half along the line $y=x$, integrate over one half, and multiply the result by $2$. (Whether doing so makes anything easier or not is a different question.) That strategy would no longer work if you want to integrate the function $g(x,y)=xf(x,y)$, because $g$ lacks the symmetry.

The second domain you've described, with the square roots, is not a square, but an oddly shaped region which you can see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=implicit+plot+sqrt(%7Cy%7C)%2Bsqrt(%7Cx%7C)%3D1).

Setting up limits of integration on the first $D$ is fairly straightforward. If you're not exploiting symmetry, but using the whole region, you want something like:

$$\int_{-1}^1\int_{|x|-1}^{1-|x|} f(x,y) \,dy\,dx$$

For your second $D$, it's not as easy, but very similar. Can you see how to set that one up, using the above integral as a model?